# Can’t set variable value to Power Apps label

Tags: powerapps

I added code in the OnStart property to set variables based on the Username information like first name. I manually ran the OnStart and I can see the variables were initialized and set correctly but I cannot assign them to the Label’s Text property. For example I have a variable named “varUser” with a Name value of “Jack”. When I set the Text property of the label to “varUser.Name” it shows varUser.Name instead of “Jack”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason entering the variable name in the Properties window adds double quotes around the variable name. Instead I entered the the variable name in fx field.